# How To Pick A Text From A List, Perform Certain Task With the Text Picked, Then Pick The Next Line Out Text In Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium

I have a txt file and I want selenium to iterate through the txt file. It should Pick the First Line, perform certain action, then picks the second line, perform certain actions as well. It should keep doing that until it gets to the 10th line, then rest for 5 minutes. Pick the next 10, rest for 5 minutes, until all the lines are worked on.

But I am stuck on the first line, its picking the last line of the txt file only. Here is my code;

```html
# Picks the first Keyword

file = open ('Keywords.txt', "r")
lines = file.readlines()
for line in lines:
    Keywordspace = driver.find_element_by_id('keyword')

Keywordspace.send_keys(line.strip())

# Togls on Title ( action to be performed)

checkBoxtitle = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='create_article_form']/div[1]/div/div[4]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/label")
# Scroll to checkbox if its not in screen
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", checkBoxtitle)
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", checkBoxtitle)


#Create With The First Line ( second action to be performed)

create=driver.find_element_by_id('create_button')
create.click()

# Clear First Line

driver.find_element_by_id('keyword').clear()

#Adds Second Keyword

for line in lines:
    Keywordspace = driver.find_element_by_id('keyword')

Keywordspace.send_keys(line.strip())
```

Comment: _But I am stuck on the first line_: Which line? What error do you see?

Comment: I think your first `for` loop works fine, but all the actions are after the loop ends, and hence only the last line is picked up. If you move your code under the first loop, then the actions would be performed for each iteration.

Comment: @undetectedSelenium ''# Picks the first Keyword'' , it picks the last keywords instead and when it gets to  ''#Adds Second Keyword'', it picks the last keyword as well

Comment: @AnandGautam I am not sure I understand. Can you please give me a sample

Answer (score 0):

This is what I  was referring to.
In this way, the all the code under the `for` loop would be executed for each iteration. Isn't it what you were looking for...

```
file = open ('Keywords.txt', "r")
lines = file.readlines()
for line in lines:
    Keywordspace = driver.find_element_by_id('keyword')
    Keywordspace.send_keys(line.strip())
    # Togls on Title ( action to be performed)

    checkBoxtitle = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
        "//*[@id='create_article_form']/div[1]/div/div[4]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/label")
    # Scroll to checkbox if its not in screen
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", checkBoxtitle)
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", checkBoxtitle)

    # Create With The First Line ( second action to be performed)

    create = driver.find_element_by_id('create_button')
    create.click()

    # Clear First Line

    driver.find_element_by_id('keyword').clear()
```

A small test code to check the iterations:

```
file = open('keywords.txt', 'r')
lines = file.readlines()
for line in lines:
    print(line)
    print(f'action_1: {line}')
    print(f'action_2: {line}')
    print(f'action_3: {line}')
file.close()
```

Output:

```
keyword_1

action_1: keyword_1

action_2: keyword_1

action_3: keyword_1

keyword_2

action_1: keyword_2

action_2: keyword_2

action_3: keyword_2

keyword_3

action_1: keyword_3

action_2: keyword_3

action_3: keyword_3
```

Comment: It didnt work. It combined all the lines in the txt file and used them as the keyword

Comment: Is it possible for you to provide the `keywords.txt` file? also where are you creating the driver? I just did a small test (updated it in the answer) to check iterations, and the iterations seems to work fine. As you can see each keyword comes only for one iteration. I don't understand the issue now. Need to see the txt file to further investigate